# How to tell _oasis or OCamlbuild to generate annotations?

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, oasis

The issue is simple: I can't find anywhere in the [OCamlBuild](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/ocamlbuild/) or Oasis manual how to tell the tool to automatically generate annotation files (.cmt) at compilation time.

Annotation files are useful because Merlin eats them up when it comes time to tell you what the type of an expression is when you are using Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your `_tags` file:

```
true: annot, bin_annot
```

But, as far as I remember oasis produces annotations by default since 0.4.4 or even earlier. So, I think, that you have problems in your merlin setup. Make sure, that in your `.merlin` file you have the following lines:

```
B _build
```

If you have deep hierarchy in your source tree, then you need to tell merlin about this. For example, if you have two folders: `lib` and `src` on the same level as your `_oasis` file, then you need also to add the following:

```
S lib
B _build/lib
```

Comment: Ouch, showed up by the IVG again, :D (also, no way! you got to that so fast! haha)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you tell oasis to tell ocamlbuild to do just that:

```
ocaml setup.ml -build -cflag -bin-annot -cflag -annot
```